# tMongoDBRow "Execute Command" Syntax

Tags: mongodb, talend

The documentation in Talend only gives the function call example, it doesn't give and example of how to use the "Execute Command" option.

I want to simply drop a collection.

[image]

I have tried adding the command as:

```
"db.products_v2.drop()"

"db.getCollections('products_v2').drop()"

"{drop: products_v2}"

"drop: products_v2"
```

None of which work.  I keep getting errors like this.

```
no such cmd: {drop:products_v2}" , "code" : 59}
```

Talend documentation leaves a lot for you to work out yourself, any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From the [doc](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendComponentsReferenceGuide62EN/tMongoDBRow) :

> Note that you must use single quotation marks to surround the string
>   values used in the command and double quotation marks to surround the
>   command itself

So you need to check the `Construct command from a JSON string` box, and write the command this way :

```
"{ drop: 'products_v2' }"
```

Comment: This still gives:  "no such cmd: {drop: 'products_v2'}" , "code" : 59